# What is the correct condition to check [when maxmemory is reached] in Redis

Tags: redis

I've quoted the following from the configuration file of Redis:

```
...
maxmemory

MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
is reached? You can select among five behavior:
...
```

And here my question goes: What is the correct condition to check when `maxmemory` is reached?

First, I thought the answer is `[used_memory >= maxmemory]`, where `used_memory` is showed by the `INFO` command.

But, now I am confusing that the answer maybe `[used_memory_rss >= maxmemory]`.

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maxmemory parameter is compared to a value calculated from used_memory, not used_memory_rss.

Now, the exact behavior is not trivial, because Redis tries to estimate the amount of memory taking in account master/slave replication, and AOF buffering. The value is used_memory (as calculated by the allocator wrapper) minus the size of slaves output buffers, minus the size of AOF buffers. Then this value is compared to maxmemory.

Comment: Can I estimate or calculate the two sizes(AOF buffers, salve output buffer)?

Comment: With Redis 2.6, you can get the AOF buffer size by using the INFO command (it corresponds to aof_buffer_length + aof_rewrite_buffer_length). I cannot find a trick to get slave output buffer size though, except by instrumenting Redis code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Kim. I think you are Korean.

so see this blog post.

http://charsyam.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/%EC%9E%85-%EA%B0%9C%EB%B0%9C-redis%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C%EC%9D%98-max-memory-%EC%A0%95%EC%B1%85-%EC%95%8C%EC%95%84%EB%B3%B4%EA%B8%B0/

It's mine, and It is written in Korean.