# Large number of cached memory will be used when Redis BGSAVE is performed

Tags: redis

One of my redis server has about 120GB memory in total. Our data(not cache) use about 44GB, the bgsave is turned on for this node.

So the total used memory is about 50GB, and cached memory is 40GB normally. But when the bgsave is performed, the cached memory will go to 70 GB. I use ganglia to monitor the mem_free, which will be about 1GB when cached memory is at peak.

Should I care about the cached memory usage? If so, is there any way to limit the memory bgsave use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15178331/3166303

Comment: @leeor Thanks for your reply. But it seems hard for me to change a server or  limit the maxmemory.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand what exactly do you mean by "cached memory"...

Anyway, if your memory is not enough to perform a BGSAVE, you can do it during a low overhead period, if the write request during your BGSAVE is zero, the memory increase is nearly zero so you shouldn't worry. Another approach is you disable BGSAVE and use aof instead, which can also serve as a persistence function and do not consume any extra memory